# Select data of all columns in row as a single string in tables

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have table which stores all deleted/updated data from all other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `delete_log` (
    `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data` TEXT NOT NULL 
)
```

Whenever i delete/update  data from any other table (having different different columns) i want to insert that rows data in `delete_log` like below query..

```
INSERT INTO delete_log (data) values (SELECT all_data_from_this_row_as_string FROM tableXYZ where id = :id);
DELETE FROM tableXYZ where id = :id;
```

right now i am using CONCAT(col1, ', ', col2, ', ', col3 ...) but this approach is lengthy because i have to write different queries for all other tables due to their different column name and counts.

Can anyone help me to do it in single INSERT query for all tables..? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that MySQL has a convenient way of concatenating all columns.

Comment: You can write a trigger to do this: Query the information schema for your table layout and generate the output that way. It will have performance impact.
Alternative: Use the information schema to generate the triggers. This prevents the realtime generation and is a bit more performant